# When assigning value to a member function pointer, the assignment tampered with other data

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, pointer-to-member

Before the assignment operation, the member variable **u** works fine, see figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRQtU.jpg)

After the assignment operation, the data of the member variable **u** is tampered, see figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5XL1.jpg)

Continuing **resize** operation will trigger an error: **read access violation**, see figure [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gATfP.png)

The development environment is win10 **Visual Studio Community 2022 17.0.4** x64 in Debug mode

Compiling by **mingw does not show this problem** and the code runs smoothly. I suspect it's a bug for msvc. In addition, this error is very strange, if merged the 4 code files, this error may or may not disappear, which is related to the code order.

Below is the complete code

test.h

```
#pragma once
class ETEST {
public:
    ETEST() {};
    void add() {};
};
```

order.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
class ETEST;

class First {
public:
    First(const char*);
    void (ETEST::* add)();
    std::vector<double> u, v;
};

class Second : public First {
public:
    Second(const char*);
};
```

first.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include "order.h"

First::First(const char*) :
    add(NULL), u{}, v{} {
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Second chk("");
    return 0;
}
```

second.cpp

```
#include "order.h"
#include "test.h"
#include <cstdio>

Second::Second(const char*) :
    First(NULL) {
    add = &ETEST::add;
    u.resize(10, 0.0);
    printf("u resize sucess!\n");
};
```

Below are my actions:

[1.create new solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvMDc.png)

[2.add code files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06mJe.png)

[3,paste the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UInA.png)

[4.Debugging, it throws an exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdpt3.png)

(I did not modify any solution properties, all use the default settings)

Comment: Might be just an intermediate value – check it again after returning from `resize`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I also thought it might be intermediate data at first. However, after running, its sure that the data has been corrupted, where the **resize** operation triggers a memory error at last.

Comment: @BonanYao When [I try it here](https://godbolt.org/z/j87d6WPes) it seems to work fine. And I don't see anything functionally wrong with the code. Are you sure the code provided produces the error you are asking about? You may be testing with something different from what you posted.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Indeed as you mentioned, with **g++**, no exception occurs. When I use **mingw**, everything works fine with the code. But in **msvc**, this problem has bothered me for a long time, it seems that only **msvc** produces this error. Yes, I tested with the same thing I posted, and I have even tried to clear the solution and recompile it many times, but it still gives error.

Comment: @BonanYao It also works with MSVC v19 : https://godbolt.org/z/1xh7n9Kr3 Are you sure your msvc build is correctly building all files and that you aren't linking to stale files? What version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: I don't know if this is the culprit, but back when they first started in C++ Microsoft decided it would be cool to have different implementations of pointers-to-members based on the compiler's guess about how the pointer was going to be used. That led to lots of mysterious bugs. I assumed they got rid of this misfeature, but it could still be around.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Community 2022 17.0.4 with msvc 19.30.30706. Thanks for attention. To ensure building all files correctly and aren't linking to stale files, I created a new project, added 4 code files, and clicked the debug button. All my operations only include creating new project, adding and copying code, and clicking debug button. I haven't made any changes to the properties of the project, and it still throw exception. Sorry I don't know how to insert a picture in the comment, I added the screenshot of my operation in the question, see Figure 4-7 in the question for details

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug. Maybe just avoid it adding a protected constructor to First that takes additional `add` and `u` arguments.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks very much for the reminder, which is probably the reason. I decided to not use pointer to member functions in the future, and use other methods instead

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Thanks for your reply, it looks like I need to re-architect my code to avoid the unexpected behavior.

Comment: See also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inheritance-keywords), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pointers-to-members) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vmb-vmg-representation-method). You can compile with `/vmg`, this effectively switches MSCV compiler to standard-conforming mode where all pointers-to-members are the same size. Or, avoid forming pointers to members of a forward-declared class. Or, use `__single_inheritance` keyword in the forward declaration.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for your answer sincerely, now my code run successfully with your help!